# Can I make bazel java_binary rule replace default jar with with _deploy.jar

Tags: java, bazel

I'd like to make Bazel always build the _deploy jar and replace it with the default created jar.

The reason is that I'd like to use the [pomgen](https://github.com/salesforce/pomgen) plugin to install the "uber" jar into the .m2 repo, for use in a maven project I am in the process of migrating.

With this config:

```
java_library(
    name = "foo-lib",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.java"]),
    resources = glob(["src/main/resources/**"]),
    deps = [
        "@maven//:junit_junit",
    ]
)

java_binary(
    name = "foo",
    main_class = "FooMain",
    runtime_deps = [":foo-lib"]
)
```

The `foo_deploy.jar` is created only when I call `bazel build //foo:foo_deploy.jar`, but I did not see a way to specify to pomgen to deploy this jar instead of the `foo.jar` file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after digging in a bit to the pomgen plugin, it seems that they automatically deploy the `foo-deploy.jar` if no `libfoo.jar` found...
https://github.com/salesforce/pomgen/blob/a54506845c554ef2ef795146bb662701f33c52d2/maven/maven_functions.sh